# Where do i find the WAR/EAR build by jenkins

Tags: jenkins, war

**I am in strange situation. I want to know where does Jenkins keep the build file(WAR/EAR) after building the project.
I checked all the folders of Jenkins but could not find it.
Does any one have idea??**

My Jenkins logs **successful** build
and according to Jenkins when I go to
[image]

```
var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Test_jenkins/workspace
```

above path. There is no war file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the message at console
the second line

"Building in workspace var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Test_jenkins/workspace "

Answer (score 1):

It should be there in your workspace, check the console logs it will mention the path where your build / packages are happening. Usually it will be in jenkins/jobs/

Comment: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ProjectName/workspace - There is no .war file. Though Jenkins log successful

Comment: I guess it shows only the code checkout activity from GIT, what is the build configuration for this job in jenkins and what is the build tool you are using to build your application

Comment: I was not using maven. Now i got it

Answer (score 0):

First You need to find `Jenkins workspace folder` which is in your case is `var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Test_jenkins/workspace`.
It should be in Your `Jenkins_workspace/jobs/projectName/builds/buildNumber/{SourcePackage}${ProjectName}/archive/SourcepackageName/subprojectName/trunkVersion/projectName.war`.
Mine is Maven Project till `/buildNumber/` every thing is same later it might change.